# Excel VBA Combine duplicate rows and add quantities

Tags: vba, excel, sum, duplicates

I have data that looks like this:

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
name 1| Item 1|   3
name 2| Item 3|   1
name 3| Item 2|   2
name 2| Item 3|   6
name 3| Item 2|   4
name 2| Item 3|   3
```

And I need a line of code to add the last column of quantities for duplicate rows and then delete the duplicate rows. So the above table should look like this:

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
name 1| Item 1|   3
name 2| Item 3|   10
name 3| Item 2|   6
```

I have tried multiple ways from other people's questions, but i keep getting "error: 400".

Here's two examples:

```
    For Each a In tm.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - a.Row
        If a = a.Offset(r, 0) And a.Offset(0, 1) = a.Offset(r, 1) And a.Offset(0, 2) = a.Offset(r, 2) Then
            a.Offset(0, 4) = a.Offset(0, 4) + a.Offset(r, 4)
            a.Offset(r, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            r = r - 1
        End If
    Next r
Next a


With Worksheets("Card Test") 

With .Range("b2:e2").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Copy
    With .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' copy value and formats
        .Columns(2).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-" & .Columns.Count + 1 & "])"
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    End With
End With

End With
```

Also I should mention that I have two worksheets and the button using the macro will be on a different sheet than the data. That seems to be causing issues too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a **FOR loop** to solve your issue:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    For y = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(y, 1).Value And Cells(x, 2).Value = Cells(y, 2).Value And x > y Then
            Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(x, 3).Value + Cells(y, 3).Value
            Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Great, this works perfectly! All I needed to do is add the cell reference to the other sheet (tm) with the data):

Answer (score 0):

Create a code module in your workbook, by default 'Module1'. Paste the following 3 items into that module, with the Enum declaration at the very top. You can change the enumerations, like NumItem = 3 would make the column in which you have the item's name "C" and NumQty automatically 4 ("D") because it follows in the next line. Right now the columns are A, B, and C.

Private Enum Num

```
NumName = 1                     ' Column Names
NumItem
NumQty
NumFirstRow = 2                 ' First data row
```

End Enum

> Sub CreateMergedList()
>
> ```
> Dim Ws As Worksheet
> Dim Comp As String, Comp1 As String
> Dim R As Long, Rend As Long, Rsum As Long
> Dim Qty As Single
>
> Set Ws = Worksheets("Source")
> Ws.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
>
> With Ws
>     ' There is one caption row which is excluded from sorting
>     With .UsedRange
>         .Sort .Columns(NumName), Key2:=.Columns(NumItem), Header:=xlYes
>         Rend = .Rows.Count
>     End With
>
>     For R = NumFirstRow To Rend - 1
>         If Comp = vbNullString Then Comp = CompareString(Ws, R)
>         Comp1 = CompareString(Ws, R + 1)
>         If StrComp(Comp, Comp1) Then
>             Comp = vbNullString
>             Rsum = R + 1
>         Else
>             If Rsum = 0 Then Rsum = NumFirstRow
>             Qty = .Cells(Rsum, NumQty).Value
>             .Cells(Rsum, NumQty).Value = Qty + .Cells(R + 1, NumQty).Value
>             .Cells(R + 1, NumName).Value = ""
>         End If
>     Next R
>
>     For R = Rend To (NumFirstRow - 1) Step -1
>         If .Cells(R, NumName).Value = "" Then .Rows(R).Delete
>     Next R
> End With
>
> Application.DisplayAlerts = False
> Worksheets(1).Delete
> Application.DisplayAlerts = True
>  End Sub
> ```
>
> Private Function CompareString(Ws As Worksheet, R As Long) As String
>
> ```
> With Ws.Rows(R)
>     CompareString = .Cells(NumName).Value & "|" & .Cells(NumItem).Value
> End With
>  End Function
> ```

At the top of the main procedure, change the name of the worksheet "Source" to whatever is the name of your own worksheet in which you have Names, Items and Quantities.

The code will first make a copy of the worksheet. Then it will sort it by name and item. After that it will combine the quantities and, finally, delete the superfluous rows.

At the end of the code the copy is deleted. If you want to be prompted to permit deletion, add an apostrophe at the start of the line "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" to make that command ineffective.

Call the procedure "CreateMergedList" from the Click event of whatever button you have for that purpose. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictionary` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, dataRng As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    With Worksheets("Card Test")
        Set dataRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In dataRng
            key = cell.Value & "|" & cell.Offset(, 1).Value
            .item(key) = .item(key) + cell.Offset(, 2).Value
        Next
        dataRng.Resize(, 3).ClearContents
        dataRng.Resize(.count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        dataRng.Resize(.count).Offset(, 2) = Application.Transpose(.Items)
        dataRng.Resize(.count).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    End With
End Sub
```